# Sketch - text lying on floor or wall

Tags: sketch-app

I am using Sketch 3 for Mac and I am wondering if there is a way to make it look like my text is lying on the floor or flush against a wall.  Or perhaps, I am asking for something like the Star Wars opening crawl look.  Is this possible at all or do I need to result to Adobe Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic Mirror Sketch Plugin claims to break the need of Adobe software for perspective effects. Check it. Unfortunately it's not freeware.